# Why NSArray's object not calling dealloc methon under ARC mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I am new in Objective-C, the referenced count make me confused :-( .
In ARC mode under Xcode 5.0.2, when I create a NSArray init with the objects, the dealloc methon of the object is not invoked, Why? Should I remove the objects from the Array manually?But it's a NSArray, how? here is my test code:

```
//------LCDRound.h file-------------
@interface LCDRound : NSObject
- (void)paint;
@end
//------LCDRound.m------------------
@implementation LCDRound
- (void)paint
{
    NSLog(@"I am Round");
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Round dealloc");
}
@end

//-------main.m---------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LCDRound.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    LCDRound* round1 = [[LCDRound alloc] init];
    LCDRound* round2 = [[LCDRound alloc] init];
    NSArray* objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:round1, round2, nil];
    for (LCDRound* shape in objects) {
        [shape paint];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where would you expect dealloc to be called in your example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSArray arrayWithObjects:…]` returns an autoreleased object,
and your program does not provide an autorelease pool. (This used to cause runtime
warnings in older releases of iOS/OS X.)

If you use

```
NSArray* objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:round1, round2, nil];
```

or add an autorelease pool:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        LCDRound* round1 = [[LCDRound alloc] init];
        LCDRound* round2 = [[LCDRound alloc] init];
        NSArray* objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:round1, round2, nil];
        for (LCDRound* shape in objects) {
            [shape paint];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then you will see your `dealloc` again.